# Snakemake: how to specify absolute paths to shell commands

Tags: snakemake

I am writing a snakemake rule that uses multiple commands as shown below:

```
rule RULE1:
  input: 'path/to/input.file'
  output: 'path/to/output.file'
  shell: 'path/to/command1 {input} | /path/to/command2 | /path/to/command3 {output}'
```

If the `/path/to/command1` is really long the rule becomes a bit unwieldy. Is there a way to specify it somewhere else as `cmd1='/path/to/command1'` and use `{cmd1}` within the rule? I know, I can use something like `params: cmd1='/path/to/command1'` and use it as follows:

```
rule RULE1:
  input: 'path/to/input.file'
  output: 'path/to/output.file'
  params: 
    cmd1='/path/to/command1',
    cmd2='/path/to/command2',
    cmd3='/path/to/command3'
  shell: '{cmd1} {input} | {cmd2}| {cmd3} {output}'
```

But that workaround requires me to specify it for every rule separately and cannot use relative paths.

What is the standard way to do such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `shell` directive takes a string as argument which you can construct however you prefer e.g.

```
cmd1= 'foo'
cmd2= 'bar'

rule one:
    ...
    shell:
        cmd1 + ' {input}' + ' | ' + cmd2 + ' > {output}'
```

Answer (score 1):

To show some power of the snake, you could do something like

```
path2 = "/the/long/and/winding/path/"
rule RULE1:
  input: path2 + 'input.file'
  output: path2 + 'output.file'
  shell: f'{path2}command1 {{input}} | {path2}command2 l | {path2}command3 {{output}}'
```

A couples of notes:

1. Double curlybraces since both snakemake and python (`f'`) will want to parse them
2. Variables as path2 above are often stored in a config-file accessed by the snakemake directive `configfile:`
3. If all your files are on the same path, you might be able to use `workdir: "/the/long/and/winding/path/"` - or set the path from the command-line (better as you snakefile will be less prone to errors if you change directories)
4. Can obviously be combined with dariober's (better) answer, creating `cmd1 = path2 +'command1'` avoiding to repeat the long path in all commands ...